# Browse messages in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis (2.17.0, but tried also 2.27.0), and I can see message count in queue grid:

[image: Message count in queue tab]

However when I want to browse them by clicking a number I cannot see them, but there is their count in lower right corner.
[image: Messages in Browse Queue]

Also when I try the `browse()` operation through the "Operations" tab I get `[]` - empty array.

Am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: Your screenshot of the queues doesn't include the column headers so it's not clear what the values represent. Can you include the entire table in the screenshot? Also, have you tried on the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) (i.e. 2.30.0 at this point)?

Comment: I edited main post with full screenshot. At 2.30.0 its same behaviour

Comment: Based on your screenshot all the queues with messages also have a consumer. It's possible that the messages in the queue have been dispatched to the consumer but the consumer hasn't yet acknowledged them. Messages in this state are "in delivery" and are not available to be browsed. Can you share a screenshot of view of one of the individual queues from the web console?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot all the queues with messages also have a consumer. It's likely that the messages in the queue have been dispatched to the consumer but the consumer hasn't yet acknowledged them. Messages in this state are "in delivery" and are not available to be browsed. However, they are still counted in the overall "Message Count." You can add the "Delivering Count" column to verify this is the case. This metric tracks the number of messages which are "in delivery" (i.e. dispatched-but-not-yet-acknowledge).